# Using sampling for p-value computations

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a search algorithm against a genomic sequence that attach a score $s$ for each search result. I want to provide a p-value score for each result:
the procedure I currently use is to search the same query against a random genomic sequence and collecting all the scores that I get in return and build the parameters $\mu,\sigma$ for the sample I got. After that I'm using the Chebyshev's inequality to compute the p-value score.

**My question is as follows**: For some queries I get a very small sample against the random genome and I was wandering what is the implications of adding to the random results all the results from the real genome to increase the sample size I use.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks to @Glen_b: Regarding (1), I forgot to add that I use the version of [Saw et. al](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Finite_samples) for the case where the population parameters are unknown, and replaced by the sample estimates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part where you use random genomes make sense.

However, using the estimates of "$\mu$ and $\sigma$" to use Chebyshev doesn't make much sense to me for two reasons:

1) Chebyshev is a population result, not a sample result (though somewhat similar results relating to samples are possible)

2) you'll get very poor estimates of the p-value in the extreme tail.

You can use the distribution of test statistics from the random genome to estimate the p-value directly (it's the proportion of results as, or more extreme than the one for your original sample). You can also compute a standard error - or an interval - for the p-value estimate.

It's not clear to me what you mean by "very small sample *against* the random genome"

Comment: I meant that there are some queries that I run and get something like 2-5 "results" from the random genome. This causes a situation where the estimations are very noisy.
(I solve this by increasing the size of the random genome)